# Prompted to create account when I attempt to login to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I seem to have gotten my Stack Overflow account in a weird state.

When I log into another Stack Exchange account, I can view my profile and my Stack Exchange account will show up there, complete with reputation and badges. Also, I'm logged into the Stack Exchange account on my iPhone, and I am receiving reputation updates and notifications of comments there.

However, when I attempt to log in via a desktop browser, I'm prompted to create a new account. I am logging in with the same Google account in all places.

What should I do?